# FA for a language which forms an AGP

Tags: finite-automata, automata, automata-theory

Suppose for a set of input symbols Σ={a,b} , 
L={ε,a,abbb,aabbbbbbbbb,aaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,...}

then finite automata for the above language(i.e forms a simple arithmetic geometric progression) will be?

Comment: I'm not spotting a pattern here. Can you elaborate on what the language is?

Comment: the strings in the language are in the following pattern:-   |ω| follows the series as {0(for epsilon),1,4,11,30,85,... } because 'a' changes arithmetically as a,aa,aaa  i.e. 1,2,3,4 but 'b' changes geometrically as bbb,bbbbbbbbb,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb i.e. 3,9,27,81 times in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great example of a nonregular language. Intuitively, for a finite-memory computer to determine whether or not a string is in the language, it would need to remember how many a's it saw so that it could determine whether the number of b's was correct. Unfortunately, there are infinitely many possible choices for a number of a's and finite automata can't remember one of infinitely many different options.

You can formally prove this by using either the pumping lemma for regular languages or the Myhill-Nerode theorem. With the pumping lemma, pick a string like a<sup>3n+1</sup>b<sup>3<sup>n</sup></sup> and show that pumping the number of a's breaks the connection to the number of b's. For the Myhill-Nerode theorem, choose the infinite family of strings of the form a<sup>3n+1</sup> and show that tacking on a number of b's appropriate for one string renders the other string not in the language.

Comment: Is it possible with turing machine?

Comment: Yep! If you can write a computer program to list all the strings in the language, you can build a TM for the language.